# PHP Inheritance of object created within a class?

Tags: php

I have a class `Second` in which is initiated through `First`. I'm trying to access `$variable` **directly**, which I should be able to do with `$this->variable`, however it doesn't seem to work.

```
class First {
    public $variable;

    public function getSecond() {
        $this->variable = '123';
        $Second = new Second();
        $Second->blah();
    }
}

class Second extends First {
    public function blah() {
        // Trying to access the variable directly, it is not inherited though
        print_r($this->variable . 'test');
    }
}

$First = new First();
$First->getSecond();
```

Outputs: `test`, should output `123test`?

Note: **I made the functions public for testing purposes. I'm really trying to access the variable directly rather than passing it through a `__construct`.**

Comment: huh? You instantiate class `Second` inside class `First` while class `Second` also extends `First`? Anyway you get what you get because it is a different instance.

Comment: Let's start with the beginning. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think it would take too long to explain, I guess I'm going to have to restructure how it's all setup. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: "I guess I'm going to have to restructure" I can only agree :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance $Second never reaches the class method getSecond(), so `$this->variable` is never set to `'123'`.

Comment: ahhhh that makes sense. So it's like a different dimension. Thank you.